# Spring Boot - How to get an IP address when using AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Please tell me how can I get IP address when using AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent ?

```
@Autowired
private LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;

@EventListener
public void onAuthenticationFailure(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) {

    // How can I get the ip address here?

    }
```

The option shown below does not work.

```
    WebAuthenticationDetails auth = (WebAuthenticationDetails) event.getAuthentication();
    auth.getRemoteAddress();
```

Comment: What doesn't work? You get an error? No address?

Answer (score 1):

I would give a try two possible solutions (I have not tested them) based on the fact that `javax.servlet.ServletRequest` interface has information about the remote host.

**1. Using `AuthenticationFailureHandler`:**

The interface [`AuthenticationFailureHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.8.x/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandler.html) has a method  `onAuthenticationFailure​(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, AuthenticationException)` that has the request `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` available.

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
 
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // implementation
    }
}
```

**2. Invoking `RequestContextHolder`:**

This context holder is able to obtain request attributes containing the servlet request currently bound to the thread through the method [`currentRequestAttributes`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html#currentRequestAttributes--).

```java
ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
ServletRequest servletRequest = attributes.getRequest();
```

Comment: This is not the right decision. This does not work. If I can't authenticate, for example, because the username or password is incorrect, I have the AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent listener initialized. Thanks to this, I want to get the IP address to limit access attempts. When using your example, it doesn't work.